# XC Testing Framework iOS(XCode 6.1) Test session exited(80) without checking in

Tags: ios, xcode, testing

I have a project in XCode which runs fine, but when i try testing it using the (XCTestCase) Testing framework I get this error 
"Test session exited(80) without checking in : Executable does not provide an architecture compatible with the current process"
The architecture setting for the project is
"standard architectures(armv7,arm64)"
From the error statement it looks like i have issues with the architecture settings of the project, which I am unable to figure out what exactly.

From the detailed log file I could get this 
"The bundle  couldn’t be loaded because it doesn’t contain a version for the current architecture."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Making sure the Valid Architectures for my targets under build settings were all set to the same worked for me.  After updating to meet Apple's 64 bit requirements I realized arm64 was missing from my test target->build settings->Valid Architectures

[image]

Comment: If you are using Cocoapods, make sure that you have version 1.0.1 or later.