# Add Test Target to existing project in Xcode 6.3

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, xcode6, xcode6.3

Note: this question is related, but the answer given there does not solve the issue for me: [XC Testing Framework iOS(XCode 6.1) Test session exited(80) without checking in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019386/xc-testing-framework-iosxcode-6-1-test-session-exited80-without-checking-in)

I have existing iOS code, and I want to start writing XCTest cases using my Xcode 6.3. I create a Test Target by clicking on the + in the Test Navigator. A test target is created for me, including a file Tests with unit tests in them.

The test starts greyed out in the Test Navigator (I cannot click cmd+T).

*Question 1*: How can I enable the tests?

**EDIT**: The answer is described in this screenshot: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s4/sh/6a5ca990-d723-46ee-bf77-2cf0ff4e70b2/1a62c472fbbeeffa595fcecd4a9fbbf7, which I found here: [Adding Unit Tests to an already existing project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865735/adding-unit-tests-to-an-already-existing-project)

In my project settings, I have the following settings for my production target (legacy):
[image: Project settings production target]
And the following settings for my test target (auto generated):
[image: Project settings test target]

If I run my test anyway manually by clicking on the Play button in the Test Navigator, I receive the following extensive error messages.

```
Warning: Error creating LLDB target at path '/Users/erwin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NyonOrder-bzkqdvtkegbjpuccyzmrgprbjqgm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/OrderWriter.app'- using an empty LLDB target which can cause slow memory reads from remote devices.
IDEBundleInjection.c: Error 3585 loading bundle '/Users/erwin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NyonOrder-bzkqdvtkegbjpuccyzmrgprbjqgm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NyonOrderTests.xctest': The bundle “NyonOrderTests” couldn’t be loaded because it doesn’t contain a version for the current architecture.
DevToolsBundleInjection environment:
XCInjectDiagnostics: (null)
XCInjectBundleInto: /Users/erwin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NyonOrder-bzkqdvtkegbjpuccyzmrgprbjqgm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/OrderWriter.app/OrderWriter
XCInjectBundle: /Users/erwin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NyonOrder-bzkqdvtkegbjpuccyzmrgprbjqgm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NyonOrderTests.xctest
TestBundleLocation: /Users/erwin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NyonOrder-bzkqdvtkegbjpuccyzmrgprbjqgm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NyonOrderTests.xctest
TMPDIR: /Users/erwin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7094B929-04BD-459E-8E83-BDF9CBFA397A/data/Containers/Data/Application/B02B9956-754B-4663-9BC2-7191B0C2BFFE/tmp
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH: /Users/erwin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NyonOrder-bzkqdvtkegbjpuccyzmrgprbjqgm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDEBundleInjection.framework/IDEBundleInjection
DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH: /Users/erwin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NyonOrder-bzkqdvtkegbjpuccyzmrgprbjqgm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib
DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks


*** Test session exited(80) without checking in. Executable does not provide an architecture compatible with the current process. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /var/folders/cn/sfcysstx0zxb13qzdj35rh040000gn/T/com.apple.dt.XCTest-status/Session-2015-04-10_13:58:25-8ifyOV.log
```

*Question 2*: Which settings do I additionally have to check/change to be able to run tests?

**EDIT** Adding arm64 to the production target valid architecture solved this particular error. Is this dangerous to add?

Comment: Check out this answer as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29789839/adding-test-target-to-an-existing-project-is-not-working/30338835#30338835